# How to restrict controller page from direct access from url in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have used several codes for restricting direct access of controller page from url, but its not happening.
The below code in controller page is not preventing from direct url access. Is there any proper way to prevent from direct access from url?

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Cont extends CI_Controller
{
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent ::__construct();
            $this->load->model('test');

        }

       public function handle($function){
            if($function=='abcd'){
                $this->load->view('testpage');
            }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HTTP_REFERER` which holds the information(address) about the page that referred you to the current page, if it's empty you can redirect it to your `404` page. Also, you should always check for `$_SESSION` and redirect if not set.

```
if( !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {

    $this->load->helper('url');
    redirect('/page404');

}
```

Alternatively, you can also use `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, but it won't help you in `AJAX` request. Read more about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and [here](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-19484.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use *`_remap()`* function inside your Controller, where we can define where to route the method.

The following code blocks all method call to that controller.

```
function _remap($method)
{
  return false;
}
```

See the **[DOC](https://blog.eduonix.com/web-programming-tutorials/controllers-use-codeigniter-part-2/)** here

Answer (score 0):

From documentation

> For the best security, both the system and any application folders should be placed above web root so that they are not directly accessible via a browser. By default, .htaccess files are included in each folder to help prevent direct access, but it is best to remove them from public access entirely in case the web server configuration changes or doesn’t abide by the .htaccess.

If you want to prevent direct access to specific methods then you can try

```
public function _handle(){ //adding _ before the method name
}
```

Or

```
private function handle(){ //private functions cannot access by url
}
```